# Python uploading images to a site through selenium

Tags: python

https://gyazo.com/4472adaefcd169a548253d6101041af8
Was recently making a bot to automatically post an "ad" to a site when launched , however i do need pictures and i researched ways to upload pictures all i could find was :Imagepath=os.path.abspath('.\folder1\subfolder2\file1.jpg') driver.find_element_by_id("ImageUploadButton").clear() driver.find_element_by_id("ImageUploadButton").send_keys(Imagepath) and me being new to python or coding in general I have no idea what ".\folder1\subfolder2\file1.jpg" accesses

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Please see [ask] and visit [help] to understand what types of questions are expected here.

Comment: thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your actual pathname put in there instead of writing '\folder1\subfolder2\file1.jpg' - that looks like it's just placeholder stuff that the person who wrote the sample code you got put in there to stand in for your actual path.

So if the image you want to upload is in \Volumes\username\bob\Desktop\ and it's called cats.jpg, you need to put '.\Volumes\username\bob\Desktop\cats.jpg' in where '.\folder1\subfolder2\file.jpg' is right now.

Comment: can you tell us what code you're using that leads to that error?